# Array length in a multidimensional array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm having difficulties understanding why once i declare a multidimensional array like :

```
int t2[][] = new int[5][10] ;
```

I can still change the length of the arrays like so :

```
t2[0] = new int[12];
```

I thought once we declare the array to be a certain length we can't change it. So how is it possible here ?

Comment: You can do this with a single dimension too: `int[] t = new int[5]; t = new int[12];`.

Comment: You're simply not **changing** the array. Instead, you are creating a **new** array, with a new length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally speaking, a two-dimensional array is nothing more than an array of arrays.  So this:

```
int t2[][] = new int[5][10] ;
```

is really doing this:

```
int t2[][] = new int[5][];
for (int i = 0; i < t2.length; i++)
{
    t2[i] = new int[10];
}
```

Thus in reality, you can assign `t2[x]` in the same way as you're assigning any other array element.

NOTE: You are not extending the length of the array by saying `t2[0] = new int[12]`.  You are creating a new one, which means that if you have done any assignments to `t2[0][x]`, then they will be lost unless you copy them over yourself.